# comparison between unsigned and signed int (to me) appears required (c++)

Tags: c++, types, sign

I am making a game (for fun) and it has a scrolling screen. The following bit of code updates the position:

```
screen_x += screen_scroll_x;
if(screen_x < 0)
    screen_x = 0;

if(screen_x > map_width - screen_width)
    screen_x = map_width - screen_width;
```

I'm struggling to choose the correct integer type for screen_x. If it is signed, `screen_x > map_width - screen_width` induces a warning "comparison between unsigned and signed". If it is unsigned, `if(screen_x < 0)` fails (with creative results) as screen_x can never be negative.

`map_width` is compared to the length of a string when loading the map and so if we make `map_width` signed the problem is shifted to that portion of code.

Many people have said that you should use the correct integer. They also say pay attention to your warnings and it bugs me that I do get warnings (get too many and you stop paying attention to them).

What would be the ideal solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not compare directly arbitrary `unsigned` and `signed ints` if you're interested in mathematically sensible comparison. That's because C(++)'s arithmetic is not your regular math arithmetic.

In a C(++) expression involving a `signed int` and an `unsigned int`, the `signed int` is first converted to an `unsigned int` and then the operation is performed (+, *, <, etc).

To correctly compare a `signed int` and an `unsigned int` you should take into account C(++)'s "arithmetic rules" and those type/value conversions mandated by the programming language and invisible to the eye of the uninitiated.

So, you could compare the two like this:

```
/* returns -1 if s < u,
   returns 0 if s == u,
   returns 1 if s > u */
int CompareSignedUnsigned(int s, unsigned u)
{
  if (s < 0) return -1; // negative is always smaller than 0 or positive
  if (s < u) return -1; // obvious
  if (s > u) return 1;  // obvious
  return 0; // obvious
}
```

As for using the right kind of integer, that's a good advice, but sometimes one size doesn't fit all. And on-screen coordinates is one such area, where it can be more than reasonable to have coordinates signed.

Imagine, for example, you want a routine to render a box on the screen and that you want to be able to draw a box moving across the screen, starting outside of the screen (moving into it) and ending outside (moving out).

If you choose the API like this:

```
void DrawBox(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned width, unsigned height, color c);
```

the user of this function will have to do some extra math when drawing a portion of that box, when a part is on the screen and another is off the screen. All because there's simply no way to tell the function that the original/uncropped box really isn't all on the screen.

Now, if you choose this one instead:

```
void DrawBox(int x, int y, unsigned width, unsigned height, color c);
```

and move that extra cropping math inside of the function, suddenly the user of this function is enabled to write very simple code. It could be as simple as:

```
for (int x = -100; x < SCREEN_WIDTH + 100, x++)
  DrawBox(x, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, 100, 50, GREEN);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the top one a shot (or something similar). I didn't think that there would be a 'nice' way out of it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When the two sides of a binary operator are of different signedness, the signed operand will be promoted to unsigned. This is an oddity in the C standard but you have to deal with it, either by casting (but in this case that would be an error) or in this case, by using a signed integer for holding both values.